# How Multi level dropdowns using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, dropdown, html-select

> CSS

```
<style>
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
</style>
```

> HTML

```
<ul class="list-group">
          <li class="list-group-item">
            <div class="dropright show">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle text-dark" href="#" role="link" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Categories
              </a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuLink">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#">Women<span class="caret"></span></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu">
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#">Personal Care Appliances<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#">Hair Dryers<span class="caret"></span></a>
                </div></a><span class="caret"></span></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#"><a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#">Jewellary<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-submenu" href="#"><a class="multidrp" tabindex="-1" href="#">Artificial Jewellary<span class="caret"></span></a>
                </div></a><span class="caret"></span></a>
              </div></a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home Furniture</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">TVs and Appliances</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sports, Books & More</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Mobiles and Gadgets</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Men</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pets</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Baby</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cars & Bikes</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
</ul>
```

> JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu .multidrp').on("click", function(e){
    $(this).next('div').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

**Dear sir,Ma'am... How to achieve multilevel dropdown using Bootstrap? above there's my piece of code in which i'm trying to show women and within women, 1.personal care appliances 2.Jewelry should show in dropdown list and within Personal care appliances, Hair dryers should show and within Jewelry, Artificial Jewelry should show**

Comment: Can you add your expected O/P

Comment: Sir like inside women i need personal care appliances and jewelry(in dropdown) and inside personal care appliances dropdown i need Hair dryers as final dropdown item and inside jewelry i need artificial jewelry as final dropdown item